# Why is my error highlighting not working?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am having problems with the error highlighting if I forgot to place ( ) or if I place a lot of letters like shsaksb it doesn't highlight the error.
The only way for me to know there is an error is by doing dotnet run.

If I wrote something gramatically wrong sorry.

Comment: Reinstall VS? Reinstall windows? Etc etc

Comment: Did you install some C# extension, like Microsoft's official? VS Code doesn't have a way to validate C# code out of the box

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Vs code is a text editor and cannot check code on its own thus you need to install some C# extension, Microsoft Official is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your csproj file in sln?, after restart your omnisharp